# Ninject and OnePerRequestModule

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ninject, ninject-extensions

I have recently tried out `Ninject` with the `Ninject.Web.Mvc` extension, and I've noticed something peculiar and, while not breaking, confusing.

In the `NinjectHttpApplication` abstract class, there is a constructor defined as follows..

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="NinjectHttpApplication"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    protected NinjectHttpApplication()
    {
        this.onePerRequestModule = new OnePerRequestModule();
        this.onePerRequestModule.Init(this);
    }
```

I have placed a debugger breakpoint here, and this gets called a few times. I cannot find any real documentation on it. In the implementation code, there is this line that catches my eye.

```
            if (kernel.Settings.Get("ReleaseScopeAtRequestEnd", true))
            {
                OnePerRequestModule.StartManaging(kernel);
            }
```

My questions are as follows...

- What is `OnePerRequestModule`
- Why is this constructor being called multiple times?
- What is the purpose of this `StartManaging` method, if the constructor is called multiple times?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15778324/do-i-need-to-register-ninject-oneperrequestmodule-with-ninject-web-mvc-3-0/15786866#

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `OnePerRequestModule` removes `InRequestScope()`d objects from the Kernel's [Cache](http://kohari.org/2009/03/06/cache-and-collect-lifecycle-management-in-ninject-20/) upon completion of each HTTP Request.

The `NinjectHttpApplication` ctor is called multiple time because IIS creates several of them. One `NinjectHttpApplication` can only handle one request at a time. So IIS generates (at least) one instance per thread.

`StartManaging` tells all `OnePerRequestModules` that they shall release the `InRequestScoped` objects from the specified Kernel after the Request has Ended.

Comment: So this is something I am okay to leave intact? It isn't something I need to worry about?

Comment: @Ciel Doc should be much clear now, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/15786866/11635 and https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Web.Common/wiki/InRequestScope