# Do I need to register Ninject.OnePerRequestModule with Ninject.Web.MVC 3.0?

Tags: ninject, ninject.web.mvc

I'm using Ninject for DI and the Ninject.MVC3 extension within an MVC4 app, specifically version 3.0.0.6.

Reading the [documentation](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Web.Common/wiki/InRequestScope) on Ninject's wiki, it appears that the lifetime of objects created with `InRequestScope` are actually controlled by ASP.NET and to properly clean up one should register the `OnePerRequest` HttpModule.

However it looks like this doco is out of date as `type="Ninject.OnePerRequestModule"/>` cannot be found.

On the other hand I read some [bits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5018333/ninject-and-oneperrequestmodule) recently that seemed to suggest that `NinjectHttpApplication` already deals with `OnePerRequest`.

My question is whether Ninject.Web.MVC 3.0 already deals with this issue or if I still have to manually add the HttpModule to my 'web.config'.

I have added the below to my config and everything appears to be working, though I have no idea at all how to test for when objects are destroyed:

```
  <system.web>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="OnePerRequestModule" type="Ninject.Web.Common.OnePerRequestHttpModule"/>
    </httpModules>
    ...
```

Do I need to manually add the `OnePerRequest` HttpModule or does Ninject.Web.MVC handle this for me?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Exec summary: No, you don't need to do anything in the `web.config`.

You could manually sanity check by:

- Binding something `IDisposable` `.InRequestScope()`
- adding it to the ctor of a Controller
- attaching a debugger, put a breakpoint in `void Dispose()`
- manually triggering a `HttpRequest`

If you hit the `Dispose`, it woz Ninject that shot the bear (and you'll have a call stack to prove it).

What wires it it? The `Ninject.Web.Common` NuGet package adds:

```
public static class NinjectWebCommon
{
    public static void Start()
    {
        ...
        DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule( typeof( OnePerRequestHttpModule ) );
```

`DynamicModuleUtility` is from `Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure` (and the call to the `Start` method is driven by:

```
[assembly: WebActivator.PreApplicationStartMethod( typeof( App_Start.NinjectWebCommon ), "Start" )]
```

(Which comes from the `WebActivator` NuGet package)

---

Speaking pedantically, [the docco](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Web.Common/wiki/InRequestScope) <strike>says</strike>said:

> To get more deterministic behavior, you can do any of the following:
>
> 1. ...
> 2. Use the Ninject.Web.Common extensions that register the OnePerRequestModule for you.

...

> You *can* register

(my emphasis). I'll make it more explicit...

---

BTW at the start of the exercise of answering this question, I had no special knowledge, just the source to `Ninject` `Ninject.Web.Common` and one of my apps.

Comment: Doh! Thanks Ruben... I ought to have considered testing via IDisposable for myself! And you know, if I hadn't had 4 hours sleep the night before I might have actually read the doco properly... Thanks for your clarifications though. Much more detailed than the wiki. Thanks for putting so much effort into the answer. Paul.