# Using ninject dependecyResolver for both MVC and WebAPI

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, ninject, dependency-resolver

I have created and MVC 4 web application and decided to use web api in this app.
I'm using ninject dependency resolver for MVC web app. and now I want to use this ninject dependency resolver for web api.
but the problem raise here mvc IDependencyResolver namespace is: `using System.Web.Mvc`
and web api IDependencyResolver is `using System.Web.Http.Dependencies`

so how can I solve this issue?

finally I want something like this:

```
// Use the container and the NinjectDependencyResolver as
        // application's resolver
        var resolver = new NinjectDependencyResolver(container);

        //Register Resolver for MVC
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(resolver);

        //Register Resolver for Web Api
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = resolver;
```

Comment: The Web API dependency resolver is a completely different interface than the dependency resolver for MVC is. You will have to create another class for Web API.

Comment: I think there should be a way, a pattrn. some thing like an adapter. because they have some common method in their interface!

Comment: The solution is simple, create a class that implements both the `System.Web.Mvc.IDependencyResolver` and `System.Web.Http.IDependencyResolver` interface.

Comment: Related / duplicated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21520417/share-a-kernel-between-webapi-and-mvc/21528440#21528440

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is a way to share same container between MVC and ASP.NET Web API.
You just need to implement both interfaces.

```
public class NinjectDependencyResolver : NinjectDependencyScope, IDependencyResolver, System.Web.Mvc.IDependencyResolver
   {
       private readonly IKernel kernel;
 
       public NinjectDependencyResolver(IKernel kernel)
           : base(kernel)
       {
           this.kernel = kernel;
       }
 
       public IDependencyScope BeginScope()
       {
           return new NinjectDependencyScope(this.kernel.BeginBlock());
       }
   }
```

Check this article for solution:
[Simple Way to share Dependency Resolvers between MVC and Web API](https://www.radenkozec.com/simple-way-share-container-mvc-web-api/)

Answer (score 4):

There is a NuGet package that does this. Add the NInject, NInject.Web.Common, NInject.MVCx and WebApiContrib.IoC.Ninject NuGet packages to your project. A NInjectWebCommon class should have been created in the App_Start folder. Add your binding for your dependencies to the RegisterServices method. In the CreateKernel method after the RegisterServices(kernel) call, add the following line:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new NinjectResolver(kernel);
```

This will let you create the Ninject dependency resolver without having to create your own override class. Easy, right?

Comment: I believe it's NinjectDependencyResolver(kernel), not NinjectResolver, this blog post expands on your approach.

http://nodogmablog.bryanhogan.net/2016/04/web-api-2-and-ninject-how-to-make-them-work-together/