# Web API and DI with Controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, ninject

I currently have no problem with injecting into the controllers that inherit from the ApiController. However when I try the standard controller the error concerning a parameterless constructor occurs.

I understand that the following:

```
 GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new NinjectResolver(kernel);
```

only sets the injection for the controllers inheriting from the ApiController.

My question is, what do i need to do to enable the controllers inheriting form teh Controller class to access the Ninject resolver?

Comment: Possible duplicate, check this answer I gave http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21520417/share-a-kernel-between-webapi-and-mvc/21528440#21528440

Comment: Are you using nuget to install ninject? What is package name?

Answer (score 0):

you need to have a different dependency resolver for normal mvc controllers.

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/hands-on-labs/aspnet-mvc-4-dependency-injection