# Ninject WebApi Issue within MVC App

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, ninject

I currently have a working MVC 5 application which uses Ninject for dependency injection.
I am now taksed with adding some Web API controllers to this project, and I want to use dependency injection within them.

I have read a couple of blog posts and understand that the WebApi DI mechinism is different to that of the MVC mechinism.

To this end I created a new DependencyResolver for use with the WebApi, as shown here:

```
public class NinjectWebApiDependencyResolver : NinjectDependencyScope,
    System.Web.Http.Dependencies.IDependencyResolver
    {
        private readonly IKernel _kernel;

        public NinjectWebApiDependencyResolver(IKernel kernel)
            : base(kernel)
        {
            this._kernel = kernel;
        }

        public IDependencyScope BeginScope()
        {
            return new NinjectDependencyScope(_kernel.BeginBlock());
        }
    }
```

My MVC DependencyResolver is shown below:

```
public class NinjectMvcDependencyResolver : NinjectDependencyScope,
    System.Web.Mvc.IDependencyResolver
    {
        #region Fields

        private readonly IKernel kernel;

        #endregion

        #region Constructors and Destructors

        public NinjectMvcDependencyResolver(IKernel kernel)
            : base(kernel)
        {
            this.kernel = kernel;
        }

        #endregion

        #region Public Methods and Operators

        public IDependencyScope BeginScope()
        {
            return new NinjectDependencyScope(kernel.BeginBlock());
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

I register the two resolvers in my NinjectWebCommon.cs with the following code:

```
var resolver = new NinjectMvcDependencyResolver(kernel);

// Install into the MVC dependency resolver
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(resolver);

// Install the WebApi Dependency resolver
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new NinjectWebApiDependencyResolver(kernel);
```

This all seems to work fine, on the first request to a Api controller, DI works, however on subsequent calls, it fails with the error:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
>   Ninject.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> ```
> Additional information: Error loading Ninject component ICache
>
> No such component has been registered in the kernel's component container.
>
>
>
> Suggestions:
>
>   1) If you have created a custom subclass for KernelBase, ensure that you have properly
>
>      implemented the AddComponents() method.
>
>   2) Ensure that you have not removed the component from the container via a call to RemoveAll().
>
>   3) Ensure you have not accidentally created more than one kernel.
> ```

Anyone have any ideas why? I know that none of the reasons above are the reason for the failure.

PS: I have looked at the following solution and it does not work for me either:
[Share a Kernel between WebAPI and MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21520417/share-a-kernel-between-webapi-and-mvc/21528440#21528440)

Comment: Are you using the NuGet packages provided by Ninject for DI? [Ninject.Web.Mvc](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc) and [Ninject.Web.WebApi](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Web.WebApi)?

Comment: Just the Ninject.Web.Mvc one.

Comment: So the Ninject.Web.WebApi NuGet is worth a look - it has the `IDependencyResolver` built-in and can be configured to share the kernel used by your MVC project... I suspect that there's something 'odd' going on with your implementation of `BeginScope`.

Comment: There's a sample at https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Web.WebApi/tree/master/src/SampleApplication