# NinjectHttpApplication doesn't work after porting to web api 2

Tags: c#, .net, ninject, asp.net-web-api2

I have ported my Web Api application to Web Api 2 and installed ninject web api pacckage. But now I am getting an error:

```
Error activating ModelValidatorProvider using binding from ModelValidatorProvider to NinjectDefaultModelValidatorProvider

A cyclical dependency was detected between the constructors of two services.
```

Comment: Do you have Ninject.Web.WebApi 3.2.0.0 from Nuget?

Answer (score 18):

I had this same issue.  I got it when I added Ninject.Web.WebApi as a Nuget package.

To resolve the issue, I had to remove a workaround that I had previously implemented.

In the previous workaround, I had set the dependency resolver in NinjectWebCommon to a custom class that implemented IDependencyResolver.

In short, if you have a line similar to `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new NinjectDependencyResolver(kernel);` in NinjectWebCommon's `CreateKernel()`, remove it.

Comment: Thank you. Seems that workaround was common place :)

Comment: This worked for me too. I myself applied the workaround followinig this article [link](http://www.peterprovost.org/blog/2012/06/19/adding-ninject-to-web-api/), before installing the nuget package Ninject.Web.WebApi

Answer (score 2):

Didn't manage to make it working. As a workaround just removed  Ninject.Web.WebApi package completely and now using hand-rolled web api dependency resolver for ninject.
To be honest, it's so simple that I don't really see a reason to use this nuget package for integration with ninject.

Comment: Hi, I'm running into the same problem however I am not referencing the Ninject.Web.WebApi package.  The only 2 I am referencing are Ninject and Ninject.Web.Common.  What was your solution to this?  Can you provide the hand-rolled web api dependency resolver you are using?

Comment: I realise that it's probably too late already, but here it is: https://gist.github.com/Deadarius/7d68b5d82a8a9ddad59e#file-ninjectdependencyresolver-cs

Comment: This gist won't provide all infrastructure to enable web api 2 injection.

Comment: Me, too. Removed the NuGet package (I couldn't figure out how it was supposed to work, esp since it doesn't implement IDependencyResolver) and used the GitHub gyst code in this SO question: // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16382982/configuring-ninject-with-asp-net-mvc-web-api