# Ninject: Getting service doesn't work in my business layer

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject, ninject.web.mvc

I searched a lot to solve the problem but no solution worked and I am new to DI and Ninject.

My problem is that i can get my service in WebUi layer but i can not get my service in Business layer.

This code work in my WebUi but it doesnt work in my business layer:

```
public IValidator<T> GetValidator<T>(T entity)
{
    var d = kernel.Get<IValidator<T>>();
    return d;
}
```

I get this error in business layer:

> Error activating IValidator{Type} No matching bindings are available,
>   and the type is not self-bindable. Activation path:  1) Request for
>   IValidator{Type}
>
> Suggestions:  1) Ensure that you have defined a binding for
>   IValidator{Type}.  2) If the binding was defined in a module, ensure
>   that the module has been loaded into the kernel.  3) Ensure you have
>   not accidentally created more than one kernel.  4) If you are using
>   constructor arguments, ensure that the parameter name matches the
>   constructors parameter name.  5) If you are using automatic module
>   loading, ensure the search path and filters are correct.

This is my code:

My interface:

```
public interface IValidationService
{
    ValidationState Validate<T>(T model);
}
```

My concrete class:

```
public class ValidationService : IValidationService
{
    private readonly IKernel kernel;
    public ValidationService(IKernel kernel)
    {
        this.kernel = kernel;
    }

    public ValidationState Validate<T>(T model)
    {
        var validator = kernel.Get<IValidator<T>>();
        if (validator == null) // or just return null?
            throw new Exception(string.Format("No validator found for type                 ({0})", model.GetType()));

        return validator.Validate(model);
    }

}
```

and my binding:

```
kernel.Bind<IValidationService>().To<ValidationService>();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Configuring Ninject with Asp.Net MVC & Web Api](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16382982/configuring-ninject-with-asp-net-mvc-web-api)

Comment: that doesn't work.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the same `Kernel` instance? You should typically have just 1 instance per AppDomain.

Comment: I get it with constructor Public Some(IKernel kernel){}

Comment: and i can see all bound service in the instance when debugging.

Comment: i am using composition root as you said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long time inspecting, I got the problem.

I have done this and my problem gone:

```
kernel.Bind<IValidationService>().To<ValidationService>()
            .WithConstructorArgument(typeof(IKernel));
```